# Pass function variable INSIDE route declaration

Tags: laravel

Let's say I have a function in my controller which retrieves users looking something like this:

```
public function index($category) {
// retrieve users depending on category or all
}
```

Now is there a way to make named routes to include the function parameter like so:

```
Route::get('passengers', 'Controller@index(1)')->name('passengers');
Route::get('attendees', 'Controller@index(2)')->name('attendees');
```

This way they can all use the same function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can not pass a parameter the action name, and there is a problem in you routing logic :

```
Route::get('/{categoryName}', 'Controller@index')->name('index');
```

And in the controller you will for example get the category by name like this :

```
public function index($categoryName) {
     $category = Category::where('name', $categoryName)->first();
     // use $ category as you please ;)
}
```

In the blade :

```
route('index', ['categoryName' => $category->name])
```

Comment: @M.Moes is that ok with you ?

Comment: not really, I want to urls to be: example.com/passengers, example.com/attendees and have them go to index(1) and index(2) etc.

Comment: What about creating two methods in the controller ?

Comment: so for every category I would have to create a specific named route AND a specific function which just calls the general function to send 1 id? that could get a bit out of hand...

Comment: they're dynamic, more can be created

Comment: Is `passengers` and `attendees` are categories ?

Comment: yes, also categories like captains or cleaners or whatever may be added later

Comment: that'll have to do, I guess I was searching for the quick way instead of the efficient way

Comment: the only problem here would be that every /name url would try to receive users with that given name, when there are only a few categories

Comment: I didn't see you problem :p can you explain it ?

Comment: wouldn't going to /home try to receive users with the home category instead of going to the homepage?

Comment: For that place your /home route above the /{categoryName} and the problem is solved :)

Answer (score 0):

> If the named route defines parameters, you may pass the parameters as the second argument to the route function. The given parameters will automatically be inserted into the URL in their correct positions

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#named-routes

So, use `route()` helper like this:

```
route('passengers', ['category' => 1])
```

Then you need to add `{category}` to the route. Also, it's really better to use `show()` instead of `index()` here. So, your route will look like this:

```
Route::get('passengers/{category}', ['as' => 'passengers', 'uses' => 'Controller@show']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can define the param in the url like so:

```
Route::get('passengers/{yourParam}', 'Controller@index')->name('passengers');
```

[View in docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/requests)

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::get( '{category}', [ 'as' => 'users', 'uses' => 'Controller@index' ]);
```

Remember to add this route at the end of your routes file in order to not to collide with any other route.

Now in your controller

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $category = $request->query('category');
    // $category will be passengers, attendees, etc
}
```

Your routes will be

```
/passengers can be accessed as route('users', ['category' => 'passengers'])

/attendees can be accessed as `route('users', ['category' => 'attendees'])
```